# Android Google Play Services returns invalid token for blogger api

Tags: android, google-play-services, token, blogger

I've been given access to the blogger API, I've confirmed that on my developer console.
I've also written some code to perform oAuth2 with Google Play Services using some of the code below.

```
String SCOPE ="oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/blogger";
GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(context, "myEmail@gmail.com", mScope);
```

It returns a token. As it should.
However, once I try to access the api using the token i get a error.

```
Unexpected response code 403 for https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/users/self/blogs
```

Here is my request:
[image]

And here is my response:

[image]

Here is my BaseActivity.java code that gets the token:

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity {

static final int REQUEST_CODE_PICK_ACCOUNT = 1000;
static final int REQUEST_CODE_RECOVER_FROM_PLAY_SERVICES_ERROR = 1001;
static final int REQUEST_CODE_RECOVER_FROM_AUTH_ERROR = 1002;
private static final String SCOPE ="oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/blogger";
private String mEmail; // Received from newChooseAccountIntent(); passed to getToken()
public ProgressDialog mDialog;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    login();
}

public void login() {
    pickUserAccount();
}

private void pickUserAccount() {
    String[] accountTypes = new String[]{"com.google"};
    Intent intent = AccountPicker.newChooseAccountIntent(null, null, accountTypes, false, null, null, null, null);
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_PICK_ACCOUNT);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_PICK_ACCOUNT) {
        // Receiving a result from the AccountPicker
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            mEmail = data.getStringExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME);

            // With the account name acquired, go get the auth token
            getToken();
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // The account picker dialog closed without selecting an account.
            // Notify users that they must pick an account to proceed.
            Toast.makeText(this, "Pick Account", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } else if ((requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_RECOVER_FROM_AUTH_ERROR ||
            requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_RECOVER_FROM_PLAY_SERVICES_ERROR)
            && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        // Receiving a result that follows a GoogleAuthException, try auth again
        getToken();
    }
}

private void getToken() {
    if (mEmail == null) {
        pickUserAccount();
    } else {
        if (isDeviceOnline()) {
            new getTokenTask(BaseActivity.this, mEmail, SCOPE).execute();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Not online", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}

/**
 * This method is a hook for background threads and async tasks that need to
 * provide the user a response UI when an exception occurs.
 */
public void handleException(final Exception e) {
    // Because this call comes from the AsyncTask, we must ensure that the following
    // code instead executes on the UI thread.
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (e instanceof GooglePlayServicesAvailabilityException) {
                // The Google Play services APK is old, disabled, or not present.
                // Show a dialog created by Google Play services that allows
                // the user to update the APK
                int statusCode = ((GooglePlayServicesAvailabilityException)e).getConnectionStatusCode();
                Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(statusCode, BaseActivity.this, REQUEST_CODE_RECOVER_FROM_PLAY_SERVICES_ERROR);
                dialog.show();
            } else if (e instanceof UserRecoverableAuthException) {
                // Unable to authenticate, such as when the user has not yet granted
                // the app access to the account, but the user can fix this.
                // Forward the user to an activity in Google Play services.
                Intent intent = ((UserRecoverableAuthException)e).getIntent();
                startActivityForResult(intent,  REQUEST_CODE_RECOVER_FROM_PLAY_SERVICES_ERROR);
            }
        }
    });
}

public boolean isDeviceOnline() {
    ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

public class getTokenTask extends AsyncTask{
    Activity mActivity;
    String mScope;
    String mEmail;

    getTokenTask(Activity activity, String name, String scope) {
        this.mActivity = activity;
        this.mScope = scope;
        this.mEmail = name;
    }

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params) {
        try {
            String token = fetchToken();
            Preferences.saveString(Constants.KEY_BLOGGER_TOKEN, token);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // The fetchToken() method handles Google-specific exceptions,
            // so this indicates something went wrong at a higher level.
            // TIP: Check for network connectivity before starting the AsyncTask.
        }
        return null;
    }


    /**
     * Gets an authentication token from Google and handles any
     * GoogleAuthException that may occur.
     */
    protected String fetchToken() throws IOException {
        try {
            return GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(mActivity, mEmail, mScope);
        } catch (UserRecoverableAuthException userRecoverableException) {
            // GooglePlayServices.apk is either old, disabled, or not present
            // so we need to show the user some UI in the activity to recover.
            ((BaseActivity)mActivity).handleException(userRecoverableException);

        } catch (GoogleAuthException fatalException) {
            // Some other type of unrecoverable exception has occurred.
            // Report and log the error as appropriate for your app.
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

}

I've been banging my head against the wall on this one. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured it out.

My build.gradle file somehow ended up having a different Application ID than my manifest. I changed it so they both match the manifest, and boom! it worked.